# Python - How to transform a list of tuple to a tuple

Tags: python

I retrieved data from a sql query and

I have a list of tuple like:

```
[(34.2424,), (-64.2344,) (76.3534,), (45.2344,)]
```

And I would like to have a string like (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344,)

Does a function exist that can do that?

Notice the `','` at the end of each tuple... I have difficulty to get rid of it

Comment: Please try to search in google before asking

Comment: Please be a little patient before voting down, my question was not finished to compose...

Comment: You should search python answers for "flattening a nested sequence." I also linked to a good way to do it in my answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using Python 2.x, then you can use:

```
>>> a = [(34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)]
>>> print ' '.join(map(str, a[0]))
'34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344'
```

In Python 3.x, or Python 2.x with a `from __future__ import print_function`, you can use:

```
>>> print(*a[0])
34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

---

You seem to have updated the format of the input data, so:

First element from each tuple...

```
>>> a = [(34.2424,), (-64.2344,), (76.3534,), (45.2344,)]
>>> print ' '.join(str(el[0]) for el in a)
34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

More than one element in each tuple...

```
>>> from itertools import chain
>>> print(*chain.from_iterable(a))
34.2424 -64.2344 76.3534 45.2344
```

However, it does seem you just want a tuple...

```
>>> tuple(chain.from_iterable(a))
(34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
```

Which you can then just use `str` on to make it a str if you so wanted...

Comment: Nice trick with the `print` function version.

Answer (score 1):

str.join() only works on strings, so you have to cast them to strings first. I could write that out, but I just read something in the Python Cookbook (my new favorite book) about this, so I'll [link to that instead](http://books.google.com/books?id=S_SJ2LaZH8EC&pg=PT235&lpg=PT235&dq=%22%22.join%28str%28x%29%20for%20x%20in%20%29%20python%20cookbook&source=bl&ots=DxjYAj6TnW&sig=ZBZUKPDgAxThY6QLhEbNVMAYgGk&hl=en&sa=X&ei=xkzsUbztHqTHiwLIi4CoDQ&ved=0CFwQ6AEwBQ).  Beazley and Jones write that for printing a tuple like this, instead of turning each one into a string, you can simply do:

```
tup = (34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
print(*tup)
```

As your tuple is nested inside a list, you can either iterate through the list and print thusly, or you can flatten the list before working with it (and there are a lots of answers on SO, and a nice one in the Python Cookbook, on flattening nested sequences).

Edit: I noticed the title changed to a request to flatten the list of tuples to a tuple, which is a flattening nested sequences request.

I'll link to the Python Cookbook recipe I noted above called "flattening a nested sequence" and also state again that there are lots of answers on this here at SO: "[Flattening a Nested Sequence](http://books.google.com/books?id=S_SJ2LaZH8EC&pg=PT222&lpg=PT222&dq=python%20cookbook%20flattening%20a%20nested%20sequence&source=bl&ots=DxjYAj7QpX&sig=y-L-cAhUIXxk2vmwua6QsKBRPEs&hl=en&sa=X&ei=lk_sUa6MPIXJiQL3sYH4CA&ved=0CF0Q6AEwBg)"

Answer (score 1):

Sorry I misread your question, but didn't vote down.

```
>>> data = [(34.2424,), (-64.2344,), (76.3534,), (45.2344,)]
>>> data_str = '(' + ', '.join(map(lambda x: str(x[0]), a)) + ')'
>>> print data_str
(34.2424, -64.2344, 76.3534, 45.2344)
>>>
```

or just flatten the list and use `str` to get the resulting tuple as a string.

```
>>> data_str = str(sum(data, ()))
```

Answer (score 0):

```
" ".join(tuple)
```

Will do the job, assuming you would like space separators.

Answer (score -2):

The `join` function of strings will do it.

```
print " ".join(arrayOfValuesYouWantToJoinTogether)
```